# \setlength{\odd/evensidemargin} is ignored when using tudsc document class tudscrbook

Tags: margins, double-sided

I'm on the last steps of my thesis. Due to my university I have to use the document class `tudscrbook` which is based on the `scrbook` class of the KOMA-Script and is available at the [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/tudscr).

However, `tudscrbook` changes `\oddsidemargin` as well as `\evensidemargin` to `13pt`. This is bullshit and breaks the proper double-sided layout of `scrbook`. Thus, I want to change it back to the proper values via `\setlength`. Unfortunately, this is not working as the MWE unveils:

```
\documentclass[%BCOR=20mm,
]{tudscrbook}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-12pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{47pt}

\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\layout
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The `\setlength` commands are ignored. How can I force to `\setlength` the margins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the documentation of `tudscrbook` on [tudscr.pdf](https://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tudscr/doc/tudscr.pdf) you can define own margins if you really need them with

[image: page from manual]

class option `cdgeometry=custom` and the command `\geometry{margin=2cm}` or simular as you need you did not told us ...

```
\documentclass[%
% BCOR=20mm,
  cdgeometry=custom
]{tudscrbook}

%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-12pt}
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{47pt}
\geometry{margin=2cm} % change values for your needs, read texdoc geometry!!!

\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\layout
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: I used `\geometry` before but without `cdgeometry=custom`. Thus, it was ignored as well. Now I was able to center the body and properly apply `BCOR`. Thank you very much!